# Training Sparse Autoencoders

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, data-science

My dataset consists of vectors that are massive.  The data points are all mostly zeros with ~3% of the features being 1.  Essentially my data is super sparse and I am attempting to train an autoencoder however my model is learning just to recreate vectors of all zeros.

Are there any techniques to prevent this?  I have tried replacing mean squared error with dice loss but it completely stopped learning.  My other thoughts would be to use a loss function that favors guessing 1s correctly rather than zeros.  I have also tried using a sigmoid and linear last activation with no clear winner.  Any ideas would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are facing a severe "class imbalance" problem.

1. Have a look at [focal loss](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52161194/1714410). This loss is designed for binary classification with severe class imbalance.
2. Consider "hard negative mining": that is, propagate gradients only for part of the training examples - the "hard" ones.
   see, e.g.:
   *Abhinav Shrivastava, Abhinav Gupta and Ross Girshick* **[Training Region-based Object Detectors with Online Hard Example Mining](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.03540)** (CVPR 2016).