# Why do sometimes CNN models predict just one class out of all others?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am relatively new to the deep learning landscape, so please don't be as mean as Reddit! It seems like a general question so I won't be giving my code here as it doesn't seem necessary (if it is, here's the link to [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1x6DOqow1dnZvy29_UZ3nHAKZLaNKr9hM?usp=sharing))

A bit about the data: You can find the original data [here](https://www.kaggle.com/tanlikesmath/diabetic-retinopathy-resized). It is a downsized version of the original dataset of 82 GB.

Once I trained my CNN on this, it predicts 'No Diabetic Retinopathy' (No DR) every single time, leading to an accuracy of 73%. Is the reason for this is just the vast amount of No DR images or something else? I have no idea! The 5 classes I have for prediction are `["Mild", "Moderate", "No DR", "Proliferative DR", "Severe"]`.

It's probably just bad code, was hoping you guys could help

Comment: You could remove some of the No DR images in training, and test your theory!

Comment: I did try to do that! Though the accuracy dropped to 35%, less than half, the model was at least predicting other classes, and I don't mind having such a low accuracy on a 6 layer CNN ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was about to comment:

> A more rigorous approach would be to start measuring your dataset balance: how many images of each class do you have? This will likely give an answer to your question.

But couldn't help myself look at the link you gave. Kaggle already gives you an overview of the dataset:

[image]

Quick calculation: `25,812 / 35,126 * 100 = 73%`. That's interesting, you said you had an accuracy of `74%`. Your model is learning on an inbalanced dataset, with the first class being over represented, `25k/35k` is enormous. My hypothesis is that your model keeps predicting the first class which means that on average you'll end up with an accuracy of `74%`.

What you *should* do is balance your dataset. For example by only allowing `35,126 - 25,810 = 9,316` examples from the first class to appear during an epoch. Even better, balance your dataset over all classes such that each class will only appear *n* times each, per epoch.

Comment: I tried doing that, and I am thinking I can also make rotated/flipped copies of the images in the other classes to expand the dataset that way, do you think those would work?

Comment: This would be considered data augmentation, as such I don't think it would balance out this gap. An augmented image is not exactly a *new* image. In that sense, I image the first class would still win over the other classes because of its diverse content.

Answer (score 4):

As Ivan already noted you have a class imbalance problem. This can be resolved via:

1. **Online hard negative mining:** at each iteration after computing the loss, you can sort all elements in the batch belonging to "no DR" class and keep only the worst `k`. Then you estimate the gradient only using these worse k and *discard*  all the rest.
   see, e.g.:
   *Abhinav Shrivastava, Abhinav Gupta and Ross Girshick* [**Training Region-based Object Detectors with Online Hard Example Mining**](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.03540) (CVPR 2016)
2. [**Focal loss:**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52161194/1714410) a modification for the "vanilla" cross entropy loss can be used to tackle class imbalance.

---

Related posts [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58213245/1714410) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64365532/1714410).

Comment: oh wow thank you, I hadn't heard of those before

Comment: @Divith I suppose if you google "class imbalance" you would come across other options as well. This list is by no means comprehensive.

Comment: Thank you for providing the links, unfortunately I can't upvote twice!

Answer (score 0):

The problem of detecting diabetic retinopathy is a difficult problem, and the dataset reflects the reality, most of the tests performed in real life resulted in No DR. But to solve your problem, there are some alternatives.

1 - The first thing is to use extra training data. In the kaggle competition all teams used extra data to train the models, choosing the correct dataset can reduce the imbalance.

2 - Another alternative is data augmentation

3 - You are using CrossEntropyLoss in your code, you can use the weight of the classes to try to balance the adjustments of your model:

```
 data_lebel = data_lebel.reset_index()
 class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight(class_weight='balanced', classes=np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]),
                                                          y=data_lebel['level'].values)
        class_weights = torch.tensor(class_weights, dtype=torch.float).to(config.DEVICE)

 criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=class_weights)
```