# Loss function for binary classification with problem of data imbalance

Tags: tensorflow, image-segmentation, loss-function, semantic-segmentation, imbalanced-data

I try to segment of multiple sclerosis lesions in MR images using deep convolutional neural networks with keras. In this task, each voxel must be classified, either as a **lesion voxel** or **healthy voxel**.

The challenge of this task is data imbalance that number of lesion voxels is less than number of healthy voxels and data is extremely imbalanced.

I have a small number of training data and I can not use the sampling techniques. I try to select appropriate loss function to classify voxels in these images.

I tested `focal` loss, but I could not tuning `gamma` parameter in this loss function.

Maybe someone help me that how to select appropriate loss function for this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Focal loss is indeed a good choice, and it is difficult to tune it to work.

I would recommend using [online hard negative mining](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65766155/1714410): At each iteration, after your `forward` pass, you have loss computed per voxel. **Before** you compute gradients, sort the "healthy" voxels by their loss (high to low), and set to zero the loss for all healthy voxels apart from the worse `k` (where `k` is about 3 times the number of "lesion" voxels in the batch).
This way, gradients will only be estimated for a roughly balanced set.

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WCg9RbYr1xQ&t=3972s) video provides a detailed explanation how class imbalance negatively affect training, and how to use online hard negative mining to overcome it.