# pytorch BCEWithLogitsLoss calculating pos_weight

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

I have a neural network as below for binary prediction. My classes are heavily imbalanced and class 1 occurs only 2% of times. Showing last few layers only

```
self.batch_norm2 = nn.BatchNorm1d(num_filters)

self.fc2 = nn.Linear(np.sum(num_filters), fc2_neurons)

self.batch_norm3 = nn.BatchNorm1d(fc2_neurons)

self.fc3 = nn.Linear(fc2_neurons, 1)
```

My loss is as below. Is this a correct way to calculate `pos_weight` parameter? I looked into official documentation at this [link](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html#torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss) and it shows that `pos_weight` needs to have one value for each class for multiclass classification. Not sure if for the binary class it is a difference scenario. I tried to input 2 values and I was getting an error

***My question: for binary problem, would `pos_weight` be a single value unlike multiclass classification where it needs to a list/array with length equal to number of classes?***

```
BCE_With_LogitsLoss=nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss(pos_weight=class_wts[0]/class_wts[1])
```

My y variable is a single variable that has 0 or 1 to represent the actual class and the neural network outputs a single value

**--------------------------------------------------Update 1**

based upon the answer by Shai I have below questions:

1. `BCEWithLogitsLoss` - if it is a multiclass problem then how to use `pos_weigh` parameter?
2. Is there any example of using focal loss in pytorch? I found some links but most of them were old - dating 2 or 3 or more years
3. For training I am oversampling my class 1. Is focal loss still appropiate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of `pos_weight` is indeed a bit unclear. For `BCEWithLogitsLoss` `pos_weight` should be a `torch.tensor` of size=1:

```py
BCE_With_LogitsLoss=nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss(pos_weight=torch.tensor([class_wts[0]/class_wts[1]]))
```

However, in your case, where pos class occurs only 2% of the times, I think setting `pos_weight` will not be enough.
Please consider using [Focal loss](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52161194/1714410):
*Tsung-Yi Lin, Priya Goyal, Ross Girshick, Kaiming He, Piotr Dollár* [**Focal Loss for Dense Object Detection**](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.02002) (ICCV 2017).
Apart from describing Focal loss, this paper provides a very good explanation as to why CE loss performs so poorly in the case of imbalance. I strongly recommend reading this paper.

Other alternatives are listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58213245/1714410).

Comment: Please reply update1. I learnt from your answer and looking into the focal loss

Comment: Please reply to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71504496/focal-loss-in-pytorch